# "No command" in recovery mode after flashing with CF auto root

Tags: rooting, heimdall

Using a Samsung 5 (Model J500FN).
I used Heimdall to flash the partitions (from CF-auto-root), which completes in download mode.

I then reboot the phone into recovery mode and just get a "Installing system updates" (or a message to that effect) and then a "No command error".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! I had issues running Heimdall as root. But it works fine as a normal user.

I also had to enable OEM unlock in the developer options.